# How to get at injectables when defining a constant in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like access to an $injectable when I create a constant in my angular app.

Is something like this possible?   How would the injectable get declared?

```
    myApp.constant('myConfig', {     //where does $location get put?
        'searchUri': $location.blah() + "/e/_search?pretty",
        'version': 0.2
    });
```

Comment: From the angular docs: "The config method accepts a function, which can be injected with "provider" and "constant" components as dependencies. Note that you cannot inject "service" or "value" components into configuration." (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

So you could inject `$locationProvider`, but not $location itself.

Depending on what you want to do, it may be better to use `run` to grab values from `$location` and store them in a factory/service.

Comment: What is your use case for injecting services in a config constant?

Comment: @georgeawg my use case is basically what is in my question.  I want a constant for something depends on what server it comes from.  Since this is always the same for the life of the app, I figured I could get away with making it a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a config block, use `angular.injector` to create a temporary injector to instantiate a `$location` service. Then use that to create the `myConfig` constant.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($provide) {
    function tempRootElementProvider ($provide) {
        $provide.value("$rootElement", angular.element(document));
    }
    var tempInjector = angular.injector(['ng', tempRootElementProvider]);
    var tempLocation = tempInjector.get('$location');

    $provide.constant('myConfig', {
        'searchUri': tempLocation.absUrl() + "e/_search?pretty",
        'version': 0.2
    });
})
```

The `$location` service also depends on `$rootElement`, so that needs to be added as a dependency in the temporary injector.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjbkhso6/).